# Is the Back of Kerdi Board the same as the front?

Tags: kerdi

I'm trying to save on my Kerdi board and I have mitered a few pieces. One fits exactly how I want it, though with the back facing out. Looks like the same stuff not he front and the back of the Kerdi Board. Is it the same?  Can I have the back of the board facing out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Schluter: http://www.schluter.com/7728.aspx

> Schluter-KERDI-BOARD is made of an extruded polystyrene foam core with reinforcement layers and **fleece webbing on both sides for easy anchoring** in thin-set mortar.

So yes!